# Modifying Properties files in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, properties-file

Is it possible to modify a `.properties` file in Tomcat, that is to add properties to it, instead of just reading them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Properties#load()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) to load them into a modifiable map-like structure. After modifying using [`Properties#setProperty()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) you can just use [`Properties#store()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) to save it back.

---

**See also**:

- [Sun tutorial about `java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)